# In Excel is it possible to have a table column that contains all worksheet names, and dynamically resizes if a sheet is added/deleted?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I currently am populating the first column of a table with a macro that inserts all of the worksheet names, but am trying to get away from VBA entirely if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with an `Index/Mid` formula, and creating a named range.

Step 1 - Create a named range, call it `SheetNames`, and the "Refers to" `=GET.WORKBOOK(1)&T(NOW())`

[image]

Step 2 - Place this in the cell where you want to start listing the worksheet names, and drag down:

```
=INDEX(MID(SheetNames,FIND("]",SheetNames)+1,255),ROWS(A$1:A1))
```

[image]

This assumes your workbook has been saved.

And of course, you can wrap that in `IFERROR([formula],"")` to hide any `#REF` errors.

(Found this thanks to [MrExcel.com](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/428957-list-worksheet-names-using-formula.html))

Comment: Thanks. I have this working now, do you know if there is a way to have the table adjust to the length of that list? Ex/ if i delete Fourth Sheet, instead of #REF! the table will just shrink by one row.

Comment: @Mark - How's the table data set up? If you delete a sheet, the `REF` can become blank (if you use `IFERROR()`), and then you could have the table data all have a formula like `=If(A1="","",[data])` assuming `A1` has a sheet name.

Comment: This is a good workaround. Ideally I would want the Table object to resize its column length but this is a clean enough solution. Thanks

Comment: P.S.  I got this to work in an unsaved workbook.